# Producing reports in Protractor (Jasmine) with details for expectations that pass

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

So I'm kind of new to Protractor. I've written a number of parameterised functions (eg `loginAs`, `navigateTo`, `enterTextIntoSearchField`, `clickButton` etc), which I can then use repeatedly as I create my specs and suites. So for example I might have a "perform search" suite, with specs for "perform search as regular user", "perform search as admin" etc.

All this is fine. I'm using the Jasmine2HTMLReporter which produces output similar to [sample Jasmine2HTMLReporter output](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b26097ab5daf4ac93b90cbd769a6bb41b5de0fd8/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f374463386c4d672e706e67)

Some of my reusable functions have expect statements, some don't (although I may yet go back and try to add them for clarity!)

The problem I have is when an individual spec consists of quite a few function calls, the list of passed / failed expectations in the report can be rather long. In the case of failed expectations it gives details of the failure ("expected Fred to equal Bob" etc). However, I would like to see something similar for the passes aswell ("expected Fred to equal Fred") - as this would allow whoever was reading the report to understand which function call any one "passed" related to - and understand the flow of the test, rather than just seeing an otherwise meaningless list of "Passed" statements.

Is this at all possible? I *could* have nested specs so that each function call was it's own spec within a "parent" spec, but this strikes me as over the top and messy, and would make the report way bigger than it needed to be? Would a different reporter give me what I want? I've not found one yet that looks like it would...

Comment: Do your failures give a stack trace? The stack trace should give the filename of the test and the line number of the expect statement that failed. As an aside, if someone wants to understand the flow of the test, they should just read the test.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I got pulled away onto another project. It's not so much a case of wanting an explanation of the failures - but details of passes too, for reporting purposes, so we can track common fails etc.

I actually got there in the end - I edited some of the Jasmine code itself, and some of the reporter code, so the various details that were omitted got passed through!